# keep getting $injector:unpr error in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

why i keep getting this injector error while I'm injecting the dependencies correctly

here's my code

this my app

```
var app = angular.module("sportsApp", ['ui.router']);
```

and this is my service

```
app.factory("serviceUrl",['$resources', function($resources) {
    var appPath = "http://localhost:7858/api/";

    $resources.serverPath = appPath;
}]);
```

and this my controller

```
app.controller('playgroundSearchCtr', ['$scope', '$http', 'serviceUrl',    playgroundSearchCtr]);
```

function playgroundSearchCtr($scope, $http, serviceUrl) {
    alert(serviceUrl.serverPath);

```
$http.get(serviceUrl.serverPath +'playground/DisplayAllSportTypes').then(typesuccess, sportTypeError);
function typesuccess(response) {
    $scope.sportTypesList = response.data;
    $scope.government = 0;
}

function sportTypeError(data) {
    alert(data.data + "Error");
}}
```

thank you in advance.

Comment: What does full error message tell you about the name of the unknown provider? Errors usually contain specific information...you ignored the important part when posting what it says. For more verbose output use non minified development version of angular, otherwise follow the link it gives uou in console for a detailed explanation on angular error site

Answer (score 0):

Problem is likely `$resources` which has an extra `s` at end. Fix all instances as it should be `$resource`. It also doesn't appear you have included `ngResource` as module dependency

Comment: I did what u said and now getting this error message **Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/unpr?p0=serviceUrlProvider%20%3C-<div ui-view="" class="ng-scope">erviceUrl%20%3C-%20playgroundSearchCtr**

Comment: That's nothing but mangled garbage you are putting in as error. Go to that link...read what it says and post something humans can read. Or use development version and see full error output but add it here in readable format